# Kubuntu 12.04, KDE 4.10, screen edges selectively working

Tags: 12.04, screen, kde

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.10 PPA. I have this setup on both my laptop and desktop. On my desktop, everything works fine. I have a 2nd monitor on the right (Nvidia GT440) and there's no issues. On my laptop, I had for a short time an LCD on the right side (depends what I'm doing). I was messing with the KDE settings and I set it so the left and right sides of the screen activated the preview all windows function. Both the left and right sides worked fine.

Fast forward, and now I am not running an additional LCD monitor with the laptop. I'm just running the laptop itself. I have it configured for the native resolution at 1366x768. Suddenly, my left side screen preview won't work. If I set the resolution to 1024x768, it works fine. Meanwhile, top, bottom, and right all work all of the time regardless. It's almost as if the system is not seeing the actual left edge of the screen.

That said, here's another wrench in the mix. If I put a KDE panel on the left side and set it to auto hide, it works fine. Meanwhile, the preview all windows feature still does not.

I also logged into a terminal at the login screen (CTRL ALT F1) and moved .kde to .kde-original, and then logged in to the GUI to re-generate a new .kde folder so I was at the stock vanilla setup. And there as well... didn't work. So it seems as if a new .kde folder won't do anything.

With all of this troubleshooting that I've done, I'm unsure of where I can go from here. What else can I look at?

Thanks for any and all insight!